Automatic waterer
I have an upside down jar automatic waterer for my quails and it works well but it has to be filled too often for the 20 birds that I have. It also takes more room than I'd like in my quail box so I thought it should not be too hard to build my own with a slightly different design. So I bought an ~18 liter (25cm in diameter, 40cm high) stainless steel canister with an air tight seal, 3/8" copper tube and some fittings, put everything together (see the picture) and water does not seem to stop flowing.
Q: Is there a way to make my design work?
In particular, it would be nice to know what matters in this case? Does having the spout on the side vs the bottom matter? Does the height difference between tank outflow hole and end of the tube play role? Tube diameter? Surface area of the drinking bowl?


Think how the original works, then replicate that. Or buy multiple units that work.

I lack fluid physics knowledge, but  I thought the original worked using the vacuum and as soon as the water in bowl closes air access, the flow would stop.

You could use a float controlled valve. Like in most toilets.

I am considering it, if I can't solve this design. Most float switches are large, take space in drinking bowl and probably will get plugged pretty quick since birds like to jump in big dishes.

air must be getting in somehow

This type of automatic waterer works based on lower pressure in the vessel holding back the flow of water (as mentioned in the comments). Then after the level in the water dish drops below the outlet, air is permitted to bubble up into the container, increasing the pressure and allowing water to flow out until water covers the outlet again.
Water dispenser containers are designed to allow air to flow in so the drink is dispensed quickly and smoothly into a cup. Most often this is archived by just having a poor quality seal at the top, but sometimes may also have a silicone one way valve or hole.
In your application you will may have to improve the seal or seal the holes. One way to test if the lid is sealed is to invert the jar, open the dispensing valve, and check for water leaks. No water should come out; even a few drips will mean air will flow in at a high rate. Note that this will not test if a check valve is properly defeated.
Another consideration is that if you start with a large air volume at the top of a large container it may take quite a bit of overflow to establish enough vacuum to hold back the water; resulting in the dish overflowing until equilibrium is reached. The best way to address this is to fill the container as full with water as possible leaving very little air when the lid is tightened up.

Briefly to expand on what @ericnutsch said, the air bubbling in the outlet (that is normally below the surface of the water) is what allows more water to come out... if there is no source of air from above.  Keep in mind that air leaks in faster than water can leak out.  Keep the air space at the top to a minimum to start.  This is the same design as is used for the water cooler at my office. It works, provided you have a good seal.  One time, the plastic bottle reservoir had a crack we could barely see but that was enough to let air and it dumped 18 liters of water on the floor.
